# swig: Set a reference between two %extended C struct

Tags: python, c, swig

I'm using SWIG to generate Python bindings for a C library. The C library provides APIs to creates objects (struct). To simplify, let's say there are two types of objects: "Houses" and "Rooms". A House object must be created before Room objects can be added to it. The House object keeps all the Room objects in a linked list. At clean up, the House object should be the last object deleted.

Example:

```c
struct House {
    struct list_head rooms;
    const char *address;
};

struct Room {
    struct list_node entry;
    int sqft;
};
```

The C functions to create/delete objects are:

```c
struct House* create_house(const char *address); // Allocate memory and initialize linked-list for Rooms.
void delete_house(struct House *house); // Free Rooms contained in linked-list and free House.

struct Room* create_room(struct House *house, int sqft); // Allocate memory and add Room to house
void delete_room(struct Room *room); // Remove Room from House's linked-list and free memory
```

Invoking `delete_house()` deletes every Room objects that the House may contain in the linked-list. Room objects cannot be deleted after the House object has been deleted because their pointers would no longer be valid. While the House object exists, Room objects can be added or removed using `create_room()/delete_room()`.
I wrote the following `example.i` to extend the basic C structs to make them look like Python classes:

```
%module example
%include "cmalloc.i"

%{
#include "objs.h"
%}

%include "objs.h"
%extend House {
    House(const char * address){
        struct House * house = create_house(address);
        return house;
    }
    ~House(){
        delete_house($self);
    }
}

%extend Room {
    Room(struct House * house, int sqft){
        struct Room * room = create_room(house, sqft);
        return room;
    }
    ~Room(){
        delete_room($self);
    }
}
```

Again, this is a simplified example. The real C library is a lot more complex (and doesn't deal with Houses and Rooms). The goal is that I can do as follows in Python and everything will be neatly cleaned up by the garbage collector (GC) when objects go out of scope.

```py
from example import House, Room
house = House("666 Elm Street")
room1 = Room(house, 100) 
room2 = Room(house, 200)
room3 = Room(house, 300)
room2 = None # Delete room2 from the house
room4 = Room(house, 400)
```

The problem is that Python's GC has no knowledge that certain objects (Room) depend on others (House) and cannot enforce that all Room objects be deleted before the House object. If the House object gets GC'ed before the Room objects, we get a Segmentation Fault when the GC eventually deletes the Room objects. In the [SWIG documentation](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_memory_management_member_variables) they describe a way to establish a relationship between C objects, which is similar to the problem I'm trying to solve. However, I can't figure out how to adapt that example to my use case.  Basically, I would like each Room object to have a reference to the House object so that the House object will always be the last object deleted by Python's GC after all Room objects have been deleted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried what is described in the following link, but can't find the right syntax: https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_memory_management_member_variables

Comment: Really great way to formulate your question.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work using `%pythonappend` as follows. Note that `%pythonappend` must appear before the `%extend`.

```
%extend House {
    House(const char * address){
        House * house = create_house(address);
        return house;
    }
    ~House(){
        delete_house($self);
    }
}

%pythonappend Room::Room(House * house, int sqft) {
    self.__parent = house
}

%extend Room {
    Room(House * house, int sqft){
        Room * room = create_room(house, sqft);
        return room;
    }
    ~Room(){
        delete_room($self);
    }
}
```